# Why is computing $e^x$ faster than computing $2^x$?

Tags: time-complexity

Here is a [very closely related, but NOT a duplicate question.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27832/is-2x-faster-to-compute-than-expx)

One time, I decided to test how long it takes to compute $2^x$ compared to $e^x$ in Python. I expected $2^x$ to be faster as in binary, the base computers use, you can just append 0 to the number 1 $x$ times. I entered into Python IDLE (Python's Integrated Development and Learning Environment):

```python
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('2**100')
>>> 0.24405850004404783
>>> timeit.timeit('e**100','e=2.718281828459045')
>>> 0.10122330003650859
```

and found that $e^x$ was about twice as fast to compute, despite not being an integer. Why does this happen? (Note that this only happens for large numbers.) The only reason I can think of is that $e^x$ can be easily calculated using a [MacLaurin series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#:%7E:text=A%20Taylor%20series%20is%20also%20called%20a%20Maclaurin%20series%2C%20when%200%20is%20the%20point%20where%20the%20derivatives%20are%20considered%2C%20after%20Colin%20Maclaurin%2C%20who%20made%20extensive%20use%20of%20this%20special%20case%20of%20Taylor%20series%20in%20the%20mid%2D18th%20century.) as $\frac d{dx} e^x$ is equal to $e^x$.

Comment: Using 3.5.2 on an ancient clunker, I get the reverse relation even using `timeit.timeit('total += e**100', "e, total =2.718281828459045, 0")`: What is your platform?

Comment: @greybeard I am using IDLE (meaning python 3.10.11) and running it on a Windows 11 laptop. Model name for laptop is `ideapad Flex 5`.

Comment: `>>> timeit.timeit('2.0**100')` `>>> 0.0073371000000008735`

Comment: Compare the outputs of both calculations. You get one exact result an one approximation. The "just append 0 bits" fails because the number gets bigger than 64 bit (common register size for integers) can handle.

Comment: I do not believe it's actually using taylor series for computing large exponential anyway.

Comment: I don't think we have a good answer on this at the moment, but you should never use Taylor series for approximation. They approximate a function at a point, where you almost certainly want an approximation on an interval. Taylor series are for analysis, and therefore can be a good starting point for making quality approximations. But also look up Chebyshev approximation and the Remez exchange algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not comparing the same operations. You are comparing two operations that look very similar in source code, but they are very much different.

`2**100` takes an integer 2, and calculates that integer raised to the 100th power using unlimited precision integer arithmetic. If you tried 2*1000000 you would get a number with about 300,000 digits containing the *exact* value of `2**100`.

`e**100` with e = 2.718281828459045 takes a floating-point number and raises it to the 100th power using limited floating-point precision. This will not give you more than about 15 digits precision and will fail with overflow when the exponent is about 800 or so. It is a total different operation. So obviously takes a very different amount of time.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is simple: `2**100` returns a bignum, with full accuracy. There is more work to handle the bignum representation than mere binary shifts. On the opposite, `e**100` returns a float and uses the built-in power function of the processor.

```python
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('2**100')
0.20831729998462833
>>> timeit('2.0**100')
0.008533199987141415
>>> timeit('2.718281828459045**100')
0.008684300002641976
>>> timeit('e**100', 'e=2.718281828459045')
0.10991410000133328
>>> timeit('e**100', 'from math import e')
0.10929809999652207
```

Comment: Can you explain how the built-in function is faster?

Comment: @PlaceReporter99: bignums are not built-in, they are emulated in software.

Comment: If that's the explanation it's a minor miracle that the difference is only a factor of 2. Mind, I'm not doubting you. `e**100` is still well within floating point range. In fact now I'm wondering if the time for that is not overly long.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout: why ? $200$ or $100$ nanoseconds seem reasonable.

Comment: Am I misreading the Q? 1/10th second for computing `e**100`? That would be `10^{-3}` seconds per multiplication in the most naive algorithm.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout: come on, realize that the unit is µs.

Comment: Then it's amazing that the bigint calculation is only twice slower.

Comment: I always thought that `timeit` gave values in seconds.

Comment: @PlaceReporter99: read the manual... A tenth of a second would make absolutely no sense.

Comment: @PlaceReporter99 It does give a result in seconds, but that result is the total for a certain number of repetitions. The default number of repetitions is 1,000,000, so the result can also be interpreted as the time for one execution in microseconds.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout: right, after all an integer multiply is not much faster than a floating-point one.

Comment: These are not integer multplies. You yourself state that they are `bigint` computations which are done in software. I was expecting that to be *much* slower.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout: these multiplies do use the ALU multiplier. For more, you should refer to Python's source code.